# datepicker + PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, datepicker

in the same page I have a datepicker and the following code:

```
    <?php

$query = mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT * FROM divulgacaoEventos ORDER BY datepicker ") or die(mysqli_errno("Não há registro de eventos."));
$row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($row != 0){
    while ($evento = mysqli_fetch_object($query)){

        echo "Evento: ".$evento->eventName."<br/>";
        echo "Local: ".$evento->local."<br/>";
        echo "Cidade: ".$evento->cidadeEstado."<br/>";
        echo "Data: ".$evento->datepicker."<br/>";
        echo "Hora: ".$evento->hour."<br/>";
        echo "Atrações: ".$evento->atracoes."<br/>";
        echo "Contato: ".$evento->contato."<br/>";
        echo "R$: ".$evento->valorIngresso01." ".$evento->tipoIngresso01."<br/>";
        echo "R$: ".$evento->valorIngresso02." ".$evento->tipoIngresso02."<br/>";
        echo "R$: ".$evento->valorIngresso03." ".$evento->tipoIngresso03."<br/>";
        echo "R$: ".$evento->valorIngresso04." ".$evento->tipoIngresso04."<br/>";

        echo "<br/>";

    }
    }else{
        echo "No registers.";
        }
?>
```

all data is displayed normally and I can order the results by date, but I'd like to associate with datepicker and only display the data (ordered by date) when I click on a date. I've tried with some array functions but it failed. Tried onSelect too but with no success. I'd appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: which datepicker? jquery UI?

Comment: @madson gr you want record in order right?

Comment: what is the data type for field `datepicker`

Comment: inputs from a PHP form (string and numbers)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>you have to add `DESC` or `ASC` what ever you want into your query..</strike>

```
SELECT * FROM divulgacaoEventos ORDER BY datepicker
```

should be

```
SELECT * FROM divulgacaoEventos ORDER BY datepicker DESC
```

## **UPDATE:**

Your concept to represent the data according to selected date is slightly different, What you have to do is, just detect the event on date select and send the AJAX request to your PHP page with some data like the selected `DATE` and the show your desired result.

**And make sure that you are familier with jQuery as well**. [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Take a look on the link that help you to generate the AJAX request after the date select.

[Jquery UI Datepicker onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396480/jquery-ui-datepicker-onclick-event)

Comment: the order doesn't mind so much. I can realized that. What I need is click on a date (yes, it's jquery ui datepicker) and show the data from MySQL in that specific selected date =]

Comment: @madsongr the concept is totally different, according to your requirement.

Comment: Ok, I got it. But is that possible to make that code you sent me, look for the events in my DB or something like take the data from a PHP query on DB? I had already tried with events being written on the code but I got stuck when it comes to connecting to the database.